# Узнать методы и свойства объекта

Tags: веб-программирование, консоль, javascript

Я подключил к проекту javaScript библиотеку, и создаю один из объектов этой библиотеки. Но я не знаю, какие у этого объекта есть методы и свойства(не знаю, как они называются), документации почти нет, а библиотека большая, и в её коде копаться не хочется.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли через консоль браузера, или какими либо другими способами и средствами, узнать названия свойств и методов у созданного Объекта?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://javascript.ru/for..in

Answer (score 2):

Как уже говрилосm выше, самый простой и очевидный способ - это for..in.
Скажем, есть у вас объект:

```
var obj = { 
        int : 10, 
        str : 'qwerty', 
        bool : true, 
        func : function() { 
                  alert(this.int); 
              } 
    };
```

пробежать по его свойствам можно так:

```
for(var i in obj)
    console.log('obj[' + i + '] = ' + obj[i]);
```

Но вполне возможно, что ваш obj будет иметь какие-то унаследованные свойства. Например:

```
Object.prototype.Foo = 'foo';
```

В таком случае прендыдущий код выведет еще и свойство Foo. Чтобы получить только те свойства, которые принадлежат конкретно к этому объекту, нужно сделать вот что:

```
for(var i in obj)
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
        console.log('obj[' + i + '] = ' + obj[i]);
```

Ну и напоследок стоит сказать, что помимо старого доброго

```
console.log(obj)
```

для массивов можно воспользоваться методом

```
console.table()
```

Правда, стандартом не является, а потому работает не во всех браузерах (разумеется, в ишаке его нет)

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(yourObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {
    x: 5,
    y: 4
}

console.log(Object.keys(o)); // ["x", "y"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Приведенный код выведет все ключи и свойстав обьекта

```html
for (var key in object) {
                console.log(key, object.key);
          }
```

Comment: чем этот ответ отличается от двух соседних ответов? в которых точно так же советуют использовать `for..in`?